# Why the command listener.listen from lib pyttsx3 printing this extra text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, voice-recognition, pyttsx3

basicly trying to follow the steps of a vid, everything is working great exapt that those lines of code:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
print('listening..')
voice = listener.listen(source)
command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
print(command)
```

it is giving me the  output:

```
listening..
result2:
{   'alternative': [{'confidence': 0.97219545, 'transcript': 'hello there'}],
    'final': True}
hello there

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Im trying just to avoid this line:

```
  result2:
    {   'alternative': [{'confidence': 0.97219545, 'transcript': 'hello there'}],
        'final': True}
```

to have the result like this:

```
listening..
hello there

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: what are you trying to avoid, the text "listening.." or the text "result2:
{   'alternative': [{'confidence': 0.97219545, 'transcript': 'hello there'}],
    'final': True}
hello there
"

Comment: just fixed the qustion, it is clearer to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason (looks like a debugging leftover) `speach_recognition` has this print [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/fba8b64262e949d31d7c1fd4f4eb17d07b3df579/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L913). Here's the [related issue](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/645).

You can avoid it by passing `show_all=True` and then do what the library does manually:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('listening..')
    voice = listener.listen(source)
    actual_result = listener.recognize_google(voice, show_all=True)

    if "confidence" in actual_result["alternative"]:
        best_hypothesis = max(actual_result["alternative"], key=lambda alternative: alternative["confidence"])
    else:
        best_hypothesis = actual_result["alternative"][0]
    confidence = best_hypothesis.get("confidence", 0.5)
    
    command = best_hypothesis["transcript"], confidence
    print(command)
```

without confidence:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('listening..')
    voice = listener.listen(source)
    actual_result = listener.recognize_google(voice, show_all=True)

    if "confidence" in actual_result["alternative"]:
        best_hypothesis = max(actual_result["alternative"], key=lambda alternative: alternative["confidence"])
    else:
        best_hypothesis = actual_result["alternative"][0]
    
    command = best_hypothesis["transcript"]
    print(command)
```

Comment: where should i put it? i didnt understend the manual thing to do

Comment: I've updated my answer, so it's more clear. Just replace your code with my code

Comment: sorry for making it hard, but this is the result: ('hello there', 0.97219545) | cant it juist print "hello there" without anything?

Comment: Update the answer. Use the second snippet to avoid the confidence number.

Comment: I appriciate you so much, thank you!! <3

Comment: cant give you a vote up because im new, it wont let me, but youve got your accept answer.